# Basically two computers in one

Tags: operating-systems, resource-management

I would need two independent OSes to run on one computer (on would be Windows preferably, but it doesn't have to be, I can get licenses if needed).
The computer has 1 CPU and 2 GPUs (one integrated and one dedicated), I don't care how the GPUs are handled.
At least one OS and the software in it has to be unable to detect that it shares resources (so VMs are not an option).
I also only have only one keyboard and one mouse, so they should be usable on both OSes as well, where again one OS doesn't know the device is shared.
Is this possible? If not, what comes closest to this?

Comment: At the same time? No you cannot.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Perhaps ask us about what you are actually trying to achieve rather than about what you think you might do to achieve it.

Comment: You can certainly have 2 different operating systems on the same machine. You can have any number of them, and just choose which one you want to run when the computer starts. But as Moab said, running 2 at the same time wouldn't be possible.

Comment: How do VMs rule out "At least one OS and the software in it has to be unable to detect that it shares resources"? Why could full virtualization (rather then paravirtualization) not work?

Comment: This is indeed an XY version, but it is something I'd like to know either way, even if there is a better alternative

Comment: I'll get a look at full virtualization, this might be a solution.